# Calling a function within a function (invoked functions)

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to get my head around invoked functions and their usage. I have a function called `addExp` - it adds experience points to the player object and determines whether or not the player has levelled up.

Here is the function:

```
function addExp(amt) {
  return function(amt) {
    player.exp += amt;
    while(player.exp >= player.reqExp) {
      var carry = player.exp - player.reqExp;
      player.level++;
      nextLevel(player.level);
      player.exp = 0 + carry;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what happens when I use it:

```
addExp(200); // adds no exp to the player
addExp(200)(200); // adds 200 exp to the player
addExp()(200); // adds 200 exp to the player
```

I have searched around online and read other questions but can't understand why it works like this - which (if any) of those function calls is done correctly? Could someone please explain, in simple enough terms, why returning a function within a function is advantageous?

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing it this way though?

Comment: There's absolutely no point to one of those two `function` layers. Why have them?

Comment: Perhaps if you didn't have the `amt` parameter in the inner function it might make more sense, you could then do `var add200 = addExp(200); add200()` and also make `add50()`, `add100()` etc? Is that more along the lines of what you're after?

Comment: It's difficult to discern what "correctly" even means in this case, since what you're doing doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.  Why do you want your function to return a function?  What exactly is the reason for this?  All three of your usages do exactly what I would expect them to do.  What's not clear is what you want this to do.

Comment: That's the point, I have heard that invoked functions are useful, but I can't figure out in what situation. James Thorpes comment makes sense, I only added the amt var in the inner function when I tested this in the console and used addExp(amt) and it didn't work, so I thought that would fix it.. xD